# Show $\binom{\lceil 2^{\frac{k}{2}} \rceil }{k} \leq 2^{\binom{k}{2} - 1}$ for $k \geq 2$

Tags: graph-theory, binomial-coefficients

Show $\binom{\lceil 2^{\frac{k}{2}} \rceil }{k} \leq 2^{\binom{k}{2} - 1}$ for $k \geq 2$ .

The proof which  I am studying uses the above result to show that $R(k,k) < \lceil 2^{\frac{k}{2}} \rceil$ where $R$ denotes the Ramsay number. I cannot see how to prove the inequality: induction doesn't work, is there some upper bound inequality on binomial coefficients which I am missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The latex is a little ambiguous but I assume you are referring to $2^{k/2}=(\sqrt{2})^k.$

In general $\binom{n}{k}\leq \frac{n^k}{k!}$. Thus,
$$
\binom{\lceil \sqrt{2}^{k}\rceil}{k}\leq \frac{\lceil \sqrt{2}^{k}\rceil^k}{k!}.
$$
Hence the inequality will follow once we show that
$$
\lceil \sqrt{2}^{k}\rceil^k\leq k!\ 2^{\binom{k}{2}-1}.
$$
Now $\lceil \sqrt{2}^{k}\rceil\leq \sqrt{2}^k+1$, and thus it suffices to establish that
$$
(\sqrt{2}^k+1)^k\leq k!\ 2^{\binom{k}{2}-1}.
$$
Since $k!\geq 2^{k-1}$, it suffices to show that
$$
(\sqrt{2}^k+1)^k\leq 2^{\binom{k}{2}+k-2}.
$$
Pulling out $2^{k^2/2}$ from the left sides yields the equivalent inequality
$$
(1+2^{-k/2})^k\leq 2^{k/2-2},
$$
and taking $k^{th}$ roots yields the equivalent inequality
$$
1+2^{-k/2}\leq 2^{1/2-2/k}.
$$
This inequality holds for all $k\geq 7$, since
$$
1+2^{-k/2}\leq 1+2^{-7/2}<2^{1/2-2/7}\leq 2^{1/2-2/k}\qquad k\geq 7.
$$
The cases $k=2,\ldots,6$ can be verified directly in the original inequality.

Answer (score 1):

I completed the proof
for odd $k$,
so here's the whole thing.

$\binom{\lceil 2^{\frac{k}{2}} \rceil }{k} \leq 2^{\binom{k}{2} - 1}
$

The RHS is
$2^{k(k-1)/2-1}
=2^{(k^2-k-2)/2}
=2^{(k-2)(k+1)/2}
$.

If $k = 2m$,
the LHS is

$\begin{array}\\
\binom{\lceil 2^{m} \rceil }{2m}
&=\binom{ 2^{m} }{2m}\\
&=\dfrac{\prod_{j=0}^{2m-1}(2^m-j)}{(2m)!}\\
&\lt\dfrac{\prod_{j=0}^{2m-1}(2^m)}{(2m)!}\\
&=\dfrac{2^{2m^2}}{(2m)!}\\
\end{array}
$

so we would like

$\dfrac{2^{2m^2}}{(2m)!}
\lt 2^{(4m^2-2m-2)/2}
= 2^{2m^2-m-1}
$
or
$(2m)!
\gt 2^{m+1}
$
and this is clearly true.

If $k = 2m+1$,
the LHS is

$\begin{array}\\
\binom{\lceil 2^{m+1/2} \rceil }{2m+1}
&=\dfrac{\prod_{j=0}^{2m}(\lceil 2^{m+1/2} \rceil -j)}{(2m)!}\\
&=\dfrac{\lceil 2^{m+1/2} \rceil\prod_{j=1}^{2m}(\lceil 2^{m+1/2} \rceil -j)}{(2m)!}\\
&\le\dfrac{\lceil 2^{m+1/2} \rceil\prod_{j=1}^{2m}(\lceil 2^{m+1/2} \rceil -1)}{(2m)!}\\
&\lt\dfrac{(2^{m+1/2}+1)(2^{m+1/2})^{2m}}{(2m)!}\\
&=\dfrac{(2^{m+1/2}+1)2^{2m^2+m}}{(2m)!}\\
\end{array}
$

and the RHS is

$\begin{array}\\
2^{((2m+1)^2-(2m+1)-2)/2}
&=2^{(4m^2+4m+1-2m-1-2)/2}\\
&=2^{(4m^2+2m-2)/2}\\
&=2^{2m^2+m-1}\\
\end{array}
$

so we would like

$\dfrac{(2^{m+1/2}+1)2^{2m^2+m}}{(2m)!}
\le 2^{2m^2+m-1}
$
or
$(2m)!
\ge 2(2^{m+1/2}+1)
$

and this is also clearly true.

Comment: The odd case isn't obvious, but the even case is quite easy to think of. Although it's not quite as elegant as pre-kidney's method, so I'll keep that as the approved answer.

Comment: Yep. It was the ceil in the odd case that made me think of splitting off the first term to get a usable inequality. I was pleased when it worked.